# chapter-first page-fancyhdr: hide title, but keep page number

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

In my diss (book document), I have headers (chapter title and page) appearing on chapters' first page as well. For each first page, I would like to remove the chapter name, and just keep the page number. This will prevent repetitions. From the second page onwards, classical heading should apply (chapter/session name + page number). I would like to have the same for TOC and LOF as well, but TOC shows no headers at all on the first page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sincerely,

Udiubu.

Below the relevant coding:

```
\documentclass[openright,a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\\thechapter}{16pt}{\Large}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{
\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{
\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\lhead[\thepage]{\leftmark}
\rhead[\rightmark]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{} %remove page number from footer
\makeatletter %insert header on title pages
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

... %other pages here

\newpage
\begin{onehalfspacing}
\section*{Acknowledgments}
These are the aknowledgments
\end{onehalfspacing}

\cleardoublepage
\begin{doublespace}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{11}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\end{doublespace}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Figures}}
\listoffigures

\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{Lorem Ipsum}

Lorem Ipsum 

\end{document}
```

Comment: The error is in the line `\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy`. Remove it.

Comment: It works, say 90%. The remaining issue is that with respect to the first pages, page number is now shown at the bottom, while I would still like to have it shown in the header. I solved it by using the following code:    `\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}}`

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
```

is responsible for the behavior you obtain. Whoever advised you to use it didn't do you a favor: it makes the `plain` page style, used by default on chapter starting pages, equivalent to the `fancy` page style.

Just remove the line.